# Container height does not take entirely even thought I used MediaMediaQuery

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, scaffold

In flutter, I used Container inside the Scaffold Widget. I gave the Height and Width of the container as below code (MediaQuery)

```
height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

Even thought my screen does not take the screen height
[image]

Comment: Can you show your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container might be taking the entire height but your items are not taking the space.

The most probable solution to your problem is, wrap your container with expanded widget.

If that doesn't work, and you have a column use the property

```
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround
```

or

```
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
```